# Keep pandas matplotlib plot open after code completes

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am using pandas builtin plotting as per below. However as soon as the plotting method returns, the plot disappears. How can I keep the plot(s) open until I click on them to close?

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_data():
    #...create dataframe df1
    pd.options.display.mpl_style = 'default'
    df1.boxplot()
    df1.hist()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    plot_data()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `plt.show(block=True)` command to keep the plotting windows open.

```
[...]
df1.boxplot()
df1.hist()
plt.show(block=True)
```

In my version of matplotlib (1.4.3), `block=True` is necessary, but that may not be the case for all versions ([Keep plotting window open in Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358312/keep-plotting-window-open-in-matplotlib))