# Why does my python app exits immediately after show graph diagram?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I use below code to show a data graph but the graph window is just shown for one second then the application exits. Below is my code. Is there anything wrong with it?

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

train_df = pd.read_csv('./data/train.csv')

g = sns.FacetGrid(train_df, col='Survived')
g.map(plt.hist, 'Age', bins=20)
```

Comment: As soon as the execution is finished the program would exit because there is no more execution commands.You can ask for an input from user to avoid the exit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep plotting window open in Matplotlib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358312/keep-plotting-window-open-in-matplotlib)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  import os    
  import seaborn as sns
  import pandas as pd
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

  train_df = pd.read_csv('./data/train.csv')

  g = sns.FacetGrid(train_df, col='Survived')
  g.map(plt.hist, 'Age', bins=20)
  os.system('pause')
```

Comment: I got `pause: command not found` error. Does this relate to platform? I am using MacOS.

Comment: Yeah , or instead of os.system('pause') use input("Press any key to close") if you using python3 else use raw_input("Press any key to close") , this will  prompt a message after program end and hit of any keystroke will close your program.

Answer (score 0):

if you use raw_input / input in these case at end of program window will wait for key stroke

```
    import seaborn as sns
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    train_df = pd.read_csv('./data/train.csv')

    g = sns.FacetGrid(train_df, col='Survived')
    g.map(plt.hist, 'Age', bins=20)

    #use this if you are using python2
    raw_input("Press any key to close")
    #use this if you are using python 3
    input("Press any key to close")
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want a user to be informed that action is required in order to break the program execution you can do it like this:

```
var = raw_input("Press something to quit")
```

The above (first) answer mentioning usage of system('pause') doesn't work with my OSX

Comment: `raw_input` doesn't work, because it let's the GUI window become unresponsive.