# How to keep plotting window open in MNE with Python?

Tags: python, mne-python

In [MNE](https://mne.tools/s%20table/index.html) with Python, I would like to keep the interactive plotting window open once the calling def is executed completely.

However, this is not achievable via the following code:

```
def get_plot():
    sample_data_folder = mne.datasets.sample.data_path()
    sample_data_raw_file = os.path.join(sample_data_folder, 'MEG', 'sample',
                                        'sample_audvis_raw.fif')
    raw = mne.io.read_raw_fif(sample_data_raw_file)
    raw.plot()

get_plot()
```

Such that, once the `get_plot()` is completed, the plot window is automatically closed.

Also, I am on Windows 10 with [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) 2020.1.3.

May I know how to handle this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the interactive plot in PyCharm. The `Show plots in tool window` first need to be disabled.

> Disable Settings | Tools | Python Scientific | Show plots in tool
> window

Then, `matplotlib.use('TkAgg')` should allowed to create an `interactive plot window`.

MNE `plot()` is based on  `matplotlib`. See the source file [plot_raw](https://github.com/mne-tools/mne-python/blob/bf08aca0bf47ee3d7a085c0a262371545e7eae2d/mne/viz/raw.py#L103-L514). Based from the [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12359099/6446053), `matplotlib` equip with block parameter you can pass to `plt.show()`. This allow the plot to be open even after the function is successfully invoke.

Apparently, mne group have include this parameter as well.

So, the above objective can be achieved simply by setting `plot(block=True)`

Then, the full code is

```
import mne
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

def get_plot():
    sample_data_folder = mne.datasets.sample.data_path()
    sample_data_raw_file = os.path.join(sample_data_folder, 'MEG', 'sample',
                                        'sample_audvis_raw.fif')
    raw = mne.io.read_raw_fif(sample_data_raw_file)
    raw.plot(block=True)

get_plot()
```