matplotlib show() displays the figure just for 1 second and closes automatically instead of keeping open
Hi am using subplots from matplotlib to plot a two signals in the same figure. I know I don't need to use subplots, and could just use plot, but for me it's more easy to understand. Anyway, the problem is that I'm trying to display the figure window, and when executing the script, the window just appears for second, enough for me to see that it opens but immediately closes up.
I have tried with show(block = True) and show(blosk=False) but I get an error.
How is this implementation wrong? Is it affecting that I'm using savefig in a line below?
The figure is saved correctly, the only line that doesn't work as expected is show().
def Ah_cha_and_dcha():
    fig_Ah, ax1 = plt.subplots(nrows= 1, ncols = 1)
    ax1.plot(time, Ah_Charge, label = 'Ah Charge')
    ax1.plot(time, Ah_Disharge, label = 'Ah Discharge')
    ax1.set_xlabel('Test Time [s]')
    ax1.set_ylabel('Ah')
    ax1.set_ylim(-1,110)
    ax1.legend()
    fig_Ah.savefig("Ah.png")
    fig_Ah.show()  # IT SHOWS FOR <1 SECOND!

When using block=True
fig_Ah.show(block=True)
I get the error
TypeError: Figure.show() got an unexpected keyword argument 'block'

What behavior do you get with plt.show(block=True)?

@BigBen thanks for the question, I have updated the post with that info.

Not fig_Ah.show, plt.show...?

I have just tried and plt.show() works, but it displays all other figures I don't need.
Is there any way I can only plot specifically that figure? Or it just works with plt.show() and I have to show all the figures used in the script?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358312/keep-plotting-window-open-in-matplotlib#comment71543920_12359099. Not sure, but perhaps plt.clf() before you create this plot. Might be wrong.

I read from "class Figure(Figurebase) ... def show (self, warn=True)"
(see attached picture)"This does not manage an GUI event loop. Consequently, the figure
may only be shown briefly or not shown at all if you or your
environment are not managing an event loop."
Is that what is happening?
I don't fully understand it but this is the solution they propose a bit below, so I guess I have still to use plt.show() and show all the images in my script:
"If you're in a shell without input hook integration or executing a
python script, you should use matplotlib.pyplot.show with
block=True instead, which takes care of starting and running
the event loop for you."
class Figure(Figurebase) ... def show (self, warn=True) )
